# What is "rose up" here, and what does it mean by "out of it" and "pantomime demon"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From *The Magician's Nephew* by C.S. Lewis:

> He never finished what he was going to
> say for at that moment something
> happened. The high-backed chair in
> front of the fire moved suddenly and
> **there rose up out of it** - like a
> **pantomime demon** coming up out of a
> trapdoor - the alarming form of Uncle
> Andrew. They were not in the empty
> house at all; they were in Digory's
> house and in the forbidden study! Both
> children said "O-o-oh" and realized
> their terrible mistake. They felt they
> ought to have known all along that
> they hadn't gone nearly far enough.

I've looked up in the dictionary:

> ***out of it***:
> English Adjective (comparative *more out of it*, superlative *most out of it*):
>
> (idiomatic) Not participating in some trend or group.
>
> > *When my old friends turned up, my wife felt quite out of it.*
>
> (idiomatic) Disoriented; not thinking clearly.
>
> > *Having the flu all week left me pretty well out of it.*
>
> (idiomatic) Drunk.

It's not quite right no matter if it is talking about the chair or Uncle Andrew.

And the pantomime demon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The above isn't properly punctuated. It should be:

> The high-backed chair in front of the
>   fire moved suddenly, and there rose
>   up out of it - like a pantomime demon
>   coming up out of a trapdoor - the
>   alarming form of Uncle Andrew.

There are two statements here:

> The high-backed chair in front of the
>   fire moved suddenly.
>
> The alarming form of Uncle Andrew rose
>   up out of [the chair], like a
>   pantomime demon coming up out of a
>   trapdoor.

The demon part is a simile; the author is comparing Uncle Andrew to a monstrous creature; because, I guess, of the sudden way he gets up from his seat.

I think the construction: "There rose up... the form of Uncle Andrew....." is intended to make it sound archaic, like a legend or a storybook.

Comment: **Pantomime demon** means "a demon in a pantomime" (a theatrical production).  It's a [theatrical trope](http://books.google.com/books?id=xHZl0yC8B90C&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=pantomime+demon) that demons pop up out of a trapdoor in the stage; basically Lewis is saying that Uncle Andrew emerged like a really scary jack-in-the-box.  More recently, *[The Grauniad](http://www.guardian.co.uk/football/2007/may/26/newsstory.sport8)* used the phrase to describe Neil Lennon: "His Irishness, his red-headedness, his character, have combined... to transform him into Scottish football's pantomime demon."

Comment: I don't particularly feel there's anything wrong with the original punctuation. The whole tone is a little archaic/poetic, but OP's only problem really is he didn't notice that **it** meant **the chair**. He just looked up *out of it* on some online dictionary, found the slang definition, and applied it incorrectly. I'm surprised *like a pantomime demon* was hard to understand though - I doubt I've ever read that exact expression before, but the meaning looks pretty transparent to me. It should be obvious even if you had to look up each word in a dictionary.

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure about the hyphen; but, there definitely should have been a dash after "trapdoor" to mark the end of that interrupting clause.

Comment: I agree that there should be a second dash. But the comma you have added after "and" doesn't look right to me. The semicolon is dubious: I think I'd replace it with a comma.

Comment: @Cerberus: Fixed.

Comment: @RMorrisey: Cool! +1

Comment: In the published work, *The Magician’s Nephew* by C.S. Lewis, it’s “The high-backed chair in front of the fire moved suddenly and there rose up out of it – like a pantomime demon coming up out of a trapdoor – the alarming form of Uncle Andrew.”

Answer (score 1):

There's no special meaning of "out of it" here. "It" refers to the chair, and uncle Andrew is simply rising out of that chair. If it's no clear, the subject of the verb "rose" in this sentence is "the alarming form of Uncle Andrew".

edit: As noted in the comments, this is the British use of pantomime, not the American. Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: Did he mean to say "There Uncle Andrew rose up out of it"?

Comment: I clarified this in my edit. The subject of the verb is the phrase "the alarming form of Uncle Andrew," which comes after the subordinate clause "like a pantomime demon coming up out of a trapdoor."

Comment: You're using "pantomime" in the American sense; in British English (and CS Lewis was definitely British, not American) *[pantomime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantomime)* is a musical-comedy production - our closest approximation in the States is probably a high school variety show, or a USO production.  "Pantomime (x)" in British English refers to a stage prop; "panto crowd" (a phrase used by British and [Irish comedians](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYBWA7wX_LM&playnext=1&list=PLBAFC998A6428215C) (see 9:48) to gently mock their audience) means "noisily demonstrative."

Comment: I agree with @MT_Head. It's the British *pantomime*, not at all 'silent mime/gesturing'. The implication here is *big and theatrically scarey* (especially to younger children). A bit like Captain Hook in Peter Pan movies (and then some!), for example. I'll upvote the answer, but respectfully suggest @jackgill edits accordingly.

Comment: OHHHHHHH.....I thought it mean mime, that why I didn't understand.

Comment: @MT_Head This is one of those cases where [TV Tropes massively outshines Wikipedia](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Pantomime). It's a much better article.

Comment: @trig - I agree.  That _is_ an awesome explanation.

Comment: Although, @MT_Head, Lewis was not British either. He was Irish.